# Name or word for the edges in the top of windows outside the building/house

Tags: word-request, image-identification

[image]

What is Name or word for the edges in the top of windows outside the building/house which are marked in the pictures? In most buildings/houses which is big where a person can stand or even sit. Not I'm not referring cornice, balcony or porch.

---

I just found, in India we call this slab. Does any agree with this word?

Comment: I'd call this a (window) overhang, I think, or perhaps an awning.

Comment: I found a few other options: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ruoid.gif. As for slab, nope. Slabs are located inside the house where we keep/store cartons etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This used to be called a *pentice* (really the old spelling and pronunciation of  *penthouse*) or a *pent(ice) roof* , but it appears that this term is no longer so widely known or used as it once was.

On Google I find many architects and builders calling it simply an *overhang* or a *window overhang*; and that is probably a better term anyway, since a *pentice* should be a sloping roof, like a fabric *awning*.

You are not alone in finding a name hard to track down: [here](http://www.doityourself.com/forum/doors-windows/374514-cornice-awning-window-overhang.html) is a question about it at **doityourself.com*

Comment: thanks a lot. But are you sure it's called Window overhang? On google if I search "Window overhang", almost everything has a sloping roof.

Comment: @T2E Well, it overhangs a window, so it's got my vote.  You could specify *horizontal* or *pitched* if you wanted to be more specific about it.

Comment: @snailboat I just found, in India we call this slab. Do you agree with this word?

Comment: @T2E I would accept that it /is/ a slab... that overhangs the window. Without extra information supplied in the sentence this is definitely not what it would make me think of, though. "Window overhang" sounds good to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

That slab or overhang above the window is called a CANOPY.

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! The system has flagged your answer as low quality - could you please [edit] it, e.g. by adding a reference?

Answer (score 0):

If it's slopped it is a **[pediment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pediment)**

Comment: Slopped?  Like swine?

Comment: Nope, it's not pediment.  Pediment, according to Merriam Webster is "a triangular space that forms the gable of a low-pitched roof and that is usually filled with relief sculpture in classical architecture"